# making a test app with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am making an app with phonegap, I used this framework before, and never got this issue. But I just installed it on my home computer, and I found thie error when I make "phonegap create test"

```
Creating a new cordova project with name "Hello World" and id "com.phonegap.helloworld" at location "C:\Users\Eloy\Desktop\test"

Using custom www assets from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/master.tar.gz

Downloading hello-world-template library for www...
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
```

Any suggestion??

Thank you very much.

Comment: `ETIMEDOUT` means the connection is timing out. Looks like there is some internet connectivity issue on your side or the server side. Disable your firewall/anti-virus for the time being and check.

Comment: I supposed, and I tried to verify the [link url] ( https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/master.tar.gz) and the browser download phonegap-app-hello-world-master.tar.gz file... why the command can´t download it??

Comment: Try this command: `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`
You might have to add `sudo` if you're on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @Keval... it worked for me... you can offer that as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is to be solved by setting the NPM registry.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

You may have to add `sudo` to the command if you're on Linux.